# Typeorm Jest mocking

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, typeorm, ts-jest

I'm trying to mock one of Typeorm module function in Jest and I want to do it in cleanest possible way. What I managed to create that works:

```js
jest.mock("typeorm", () => ({
    __esModule: true,
    getCustomRepository: jest.fn(),
    PrimaryGeneratedColumn: jest.fn(),
    Column: jest.fn(),
    CreateDateColumn: jest.fn(),
    UpdateDateColumn: jest.fn(),
    Entity: jest.fn(),
    EntityRepository: jest.fn(),
    Repository: jest.fn(),
}));
```

But I want to mock only *getCustomReposity* and when I leave mock only for that function:

```js
jest.mock("typeorm", () => ({
    __esModule: true,
    getCustomRepository: jest.fn(),
}));
```

Tests don't even run, because entity and repository use some decorators and classes from Typeorm. I also tried to generate mocks for whole module:

```js
jest.mock("typeorm", () => jest.createMockFromModule("typeorm"));
```

I got errors for generated mock decorators:

```
TypeError: decorator is not a function
    2 |
    3 | @Entity({ name: "users" })
  > 4 | export class User {
```

Is there an way to create such mock in cleaner way than I did?

Comment: Anything new on that issue?

Answer (score 7):

Your code requires more than what you mock.

If you mock

```
jest.mock("typeorm", () => ({
    __esModule: true,
    getCustomRepository: jest.fn(),
}));
```

Then in you code, `import { Entity} from 'typeorm';`, now `Entiry` is undefined. The same for other attributes except `getCustomRepository`.

You can fix that issue with your first solution, or just mock what you want to mock and return another attribute as actual logic.

```
jest.mock('typeorm', () => {
  const actual = jest.requireActual('typeorm');
  return {
    ...actual,
    getCustomRepository: jest.fn(),
  }
});
```

Or mock all attributes of `typeorm`:

```
jest.mock('typeorm');
```

Comment: Mocking all attributes causes same problem with decorators as I describe at the end. I thought that your solution with returning actual logic would be the answer, but that caused another error somewhere inside typeorm. It looks like my solution best suits my needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can also mock `getCustomRepository` this way:

```
import typeorm = require('typeorm');

describe('Your test suit', () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    typeorm.getCustomRepository = jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
      yourMethod: jest.fn(),
    });
  });

  it('your test case', () => {});
});
```